# How to exit a user promt/input whether there is or isn't input provided

Tags: java

I have a part of my code where i have to exit the user input after a short amount of time whether there is an input or not. I have searched for answers but they are require threads (which i do not intend to use), or are otherwise not useable for the code i am trying to write.
What i need/have:
1. user may enter a char
2. after the certain amount of time if the char is not entered then the program will proceed with other actions and exit the input section.

im using "c.readChar();"
but it pauses my program until the char is entered, i need it to continue if a certain amount of time has passed even if there is no input by the user. Any help would be useful!

Comment: How about showing us some code. How are we supposed to know what kind of class `c` even is?

Comment: You can not do it without Thread. The Thread is there to do the task in background and if you don't use you can not continue in your code. I don't know why you don't want to use it ([Threads](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html)).

Comment: It seems likely that you will need to use a **timer**.  For Swing app - [`Swing Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), otherwise - [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in `System.in` called [`available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) which you can use.

The way of using it would be to call it once and again (don't forget to sleep a little to avoid consuming too much CPU power) during some time. And if after the allotted time that method continues to return `0` then you can assume there was no input. But if the method returns something greater than zero, then you go on and call the `read` method.

Other option would be to create a form with Swing, but that would require using Threads.